# Adding strings to numbers and numbers to strings

Tags: javascript, types, concatenation, type-conversion

I tried something in my console that I don't quite comprehend.

If you add 2 + 3 + "hello" it concatenates to "5hello"

However, if you reserve this and add 'hello' + 2 + 3 it concatenates to 'hello23'

Why? My guess is because JavaScript looks at the first data type and tries to convert it to that type? Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: The `+` operator is left-to-right associative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition (and other associative operators) are processed in order, left-to-right. So

```
2 + 3 + "hello"
```

is like writing

```
(2 + 3) + "hello"
```

or

```
5 + "hello"
```

first the addition, then the conversion/concatenation. On the other hand,

```
"hello" + 2 + 3
```

is like:

```
("hello" + 2) + 3
```

which works out to

```
"hello2" + 3
```

or

```
"hello23"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple order of operations really:

```
2 + 2 + "hello" //2 + 2 is evaluated first, resulting in 4. 4 + "hello" results in "4hello";
"hello" + 2 + 3 //"hello" + 2 is evaluated first, turning the result to a string, and then "hello2" + 3 is done.
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `2 + 2 + "hello"` is evaluated this way:

1. Find any operators and push them on the operator stack: stack: +, +
2. Find any symbols and push them on the operand stack: stack: 2, 2, "hello"
3. Take the first operator from the operator stack and
   the first 2 operands from the operands stack, do: 2 + 2 = 4
4. Take the first operator and the first 2 operands, do: 4 + "hello"
   = "4hello"

Mind you, JS automatic type conversion works this way with the + operator (which is both addition and concatenation), it may (and does) work differently in other places. `4 - "hello"` will make no sense and `"0" == true` will evaluate to false whereas `0 == ''` stands. This is one of the reasons Javascript is one of the most beloved languages of today.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to the **coercion**. Type coercion means that when the operands of an operator are different types, one of them will be **converted to an "equivalent" value** of the other operand type. The operand to take into account depends on the hierarchy of "data-type" (though JavaScript is typeless) and the operations are executed from **left-to-right**. For instance:

```
//from left to right
2 + 3 + "hello"

//performs the addition, then does coercion to "string" and concatenates the text
(2 + 3) + "hello"
```

this results in `"5hello"`

In counterpart

```
//from left to right
'hello' + 2 + 3

//string concatenation is the first, all subsequent values will do coercion to string
"hello23"
```

Unless you use parentheses, which takes higher precedence

```
'hello' + (2 + 3)
```

It returns `"hello5"`